How are ECS and DoD combined?
Where is this array of components over whitch queries are done to run through systems? How do the components get into those arrays? How does the query system work?
Does this combined system even have this entity that contains references to the components or is entity just a index in a set of arrays?

As someone who used to work for a company called ECS that occasionally does work for the US Department of Defense, i was more than a little curious about this question til i actually read it.

@cHao the curse of abbreviations :D Doesent always mean what you think

I believe that ECS is a form of DoD.
None-the-less, ECS has many implementations, and you can roll your own without risk of some programming police hauling you away.
ECS could be implemented with the Entity being nothing more than an ID — so not even an Entity array.  Then there are Component tables that are indexed by the Entity ID.  This has the advantage of no secondary indexing.  However, a problem with this approach is that when an Entity doesn't have or isn't associated with a particular component, it's entry in the corresponding Component array goes unused, and this has two drawbacks: (1) that DoD is supposed to address, namely that memory is supposed to be used densely, meaning with no holes for best usage of the caches, and (2) that you have to check somehow if a particular entity has this component or not, meaning you'll need some way of indicating empty or blank, and also that Systems will need to condition on whether that component exists or not, which messes with modern branch prediction hardware during traversal of Component's arrays.
So, there are various solutions to these drawbacks, which themselves increase overhead and are thus tradeoffs.  One solution is that there is a main Entity array, which may hold mappings to various indexes in the various component arrays, and also may hold a bitmask indicating which components are relevant to that Entity.
The latter would be used by a System traversing the Entities, looking for at least several components together on each Component in order to perform its operations.  This will incur some conditional logic at a top level, but the bitmask can be designed to check presence of multiple components at the same time, so eliminating some additional checks.
The former would be used so that the various Component arrays can be kept fully dense.
Some properties are manifest as presence in a "Component" (really more of a list) such as visible or not.  If an Entity is in the visible list, it is visible and we don't need to test anything further on that.  If such a Component or List is traversed from scratch (rather than searching through an Entity array), then component array elements will presumably need to contain the Entity Id for further query into other Component tables, otherwise that is not needed.
There is no perfect way to both minimize data size, maximize cache usage, and minimize conditional logic, so which approach is best for you will depend on the particulars of your workload, and also will probably vary based on CPU and cache internals.  If you have a lot of optional components, an indexing Entity array may help, while just a few might do better without.

Hmm... i see. But if you look at it from the angle of game engine. Like the Unity DOTS. Developer can freely create new components and systems without having to manually register them. Unity does something behind the scenes. Most likely using reflection. But how would one implement such system where the amount of different components is not known beforehand?
